# Can not install VS Team System 2008 on Windows 7 Ultimate (64bit)

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to install VS TS 2008 on W7 Ultimate (64bit), but I have run into errors during the setup.

Please take note that I have tried to mount the iso to a virtual drive, and also extracted the iso contents to a local folder. Both methods have failed and produce the same error log below.

> [10/26/09,03:02:40] Runtime Pre-requisites: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Runtime Pre-requisites. MSI returned error code 1603
>   [10/26/09,03:02:42] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Runtime Pre-requisites is not installed.
>   [10/26/09,03:02:42] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.

And the list goes on and on.. This is a fresh install of W7, and I have not installed Microsoft Office 2007 at all yet, not sure if it would be causing my errors right now.. I appreciate any help I can get thank you.

Comment: the error states that the prerequisites was not installed. When you started the install, did you see any screen that informed you that prerequisites was being installed ?

Comment: Please can you post the full log or at least a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN forum reference about this problem

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/c1f520fd-1966-4927-a7b3-7100747b19aa?prof=required